# how to run bundle install on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: json, bundle

I have a problems to run the bundle install on my PC. The return is:

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> current directory: /tmp/bundler20170309-28068-jc2jotsqlite3-1.3.13/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/ext/sqlite3
>   /usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170309-28068-19m0tjz.rb extconf.rb
>   mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20170309-28068-jc2jotsqlite3-1.3.13/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13 for inspection.
>   Results logged to /tmp/bundler20170309-28068-jc2jotsqlite3-1.3.13/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
>   Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
>   An error occurred while installing json (1.8.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.6'` succeeds before bundling.

I try run gem install json -v '1.8.6' but it did not work.

Can someone help me?

Sorry my english.